# Arch+GNOME: Oh no! Something has gone wrong

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, nvidia

I installed Arch Linux 2016
and installed the following packages in this order:

- `nvidia` and `nvidia-libgl` (then rebooted)
- `xorg`
- `xorg-server`
- `xorg-server-utils`
- `xorg-apps`
- `gnome` `gnome-extra`

My system configuration:

- Nvidia GeForce 820M
- Intel HD graphics 4400
- Intel i3 processor

After reboot, I get this error:

[image: "Oh no! Something has gone wrong" screen]

Complete log files (output of `journal -b`) is pasted here: [https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/17953922/](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/17953922/%C2%A0) 
You need to be logged in to ubuntu.com to view this paste.

**NOTE:**

Installing `mesa-libgl` by replacing `nvidia-libgl` solves the problem, **but** that is not what I want. 
I want to use `nvidia-libgl` for better performance of my graphic card,
not the open source `mesa-libgl`.

Comment: Yo might be running out of disk space or memory. After the problem occurs, look at disk usage with `df` and check RAM with `free`. You may need to increase a partition's size. Also GNOME is pretty memory-intensive, how much RAM do you have?

Comment: What happens if you start `tmux` and then `sudo systemctl restart gdm`, (and then later `tmux attach`, if so desired)?

Also, do you have the correct nvidia drivers installed? There are several nvidia drivers available in the package repository.

Answer (score 1):

During GNU GRUB boot screen:

1. press e instead of enter
2. scroll down in emacs-like screen editing to line starting with linux
3. append in the end after usually quiet: init=/bin/bash
4. press F10 or ctrl+x to boot

This way even if the UI fails you will boot into root bash and you can disable it to reboot and fix it.

Once rebooted after previous steps, one way of disabling it is:

1. systemctl disable gdm
2. reboot

Now you're all set with wifi and everything in terminal view which will allow you to find a proper solution which include but not limited to:

1. Finding old gnome-shell versions in /var/cache/pacman/pkg and installing with pacman -U
2. Changing the nvidia lib to mesa if it works for you
3. Passing the flags for gdm (various ways) if it works for you
4. Waiting for an official fix

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell

could allow you to reinstall gdm, from the terminal. if you have grub, it will be the same process as above, but instead of ubuntu, it will be arch...

Comment: I have reinstalled GDM several times. No good changes. The problem remains. *BTW I noticed you are a new user here! Welcome to U&L community. Enjoy tour stay*

Comment: thank you by the way :) . i got the same problem on debian when i tried updating x-org with aptitude and accidentally deleted gdm, but from what your saying, and what i can see in your logs, it might have something to do with: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1274013